# I need help in simplifying a Boolean expression.

Tags: boolean-algebra

My starting point was `(A+D)*(A+B+C)*(~A+C+~D)`

And I should end at `~A*B*D +A*~D +C*D` (according to online solvers.)

But when I do it by hand on a paper I end up with this:
`~A*B*D +A*~D +C*D +A*C`

And for the life of me I can't figure out how to simplify and get rid of the extra `+A*C`

Comment: Does $p+q$ mean $p\land q$? Does $pq$ mean $p\lor q$?

Comment: + is OR, * is AND, ~is NOT;
p+q was p∨q and pq was p∧q if i recall correctly

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize using asteriks to show multiplication would make the text italics and whatnot.

Comment: use `p\land q` for $p\land q$, and use `p\lor q` for $p\lor q$, and use `\sim` for $\sim$ :)

Comment: Thanks Rócherz for editing and fixing my question and thank you Nosrati, for explaining how to get the correct symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By applying the distributive law you get that $(A \lor D) \land (A \lor B \lor C)\land ( \sim A \lor C \, \lor \sim D)$ is equivalent to

$$
(A \land A \land \sim A) \lor (A \land A \land C) \lor (A \land A \land \sim D) \lor (A \land B \land \sim A) \lor (A \land B \land C) \lor (A \land B \land \sim D) \lor (A \land C \land \sim A) \lor (A \land C \land C) \lor (A \land C \land \sim D) \lor (D \land A \land \sim A) \lor (D \land A \land C) \lor (D \land A \land \sim D) \lor (D \land B \land \sim A) \lor (D \land B \land C) \lor (D \land B \land \sim D) \lor (D \land C \land \sim A) \lor (D \land C \land C) \lor (D \land C \land \sim D)
$$

We now delete all the disjuncts that are equivalent to $0$  and we get rid of all the redundant terms. We get that the original expression is equivalent to

$$
 (A \land C) \lor (A \land \sim D)  \lor (A \land B \land C) \lor (A \land B \land \sim D) \lor  (A \land C ) \lor (A \land C \land \sim D)  \lor (D \land A \land C) \lor (D \land B \land \sim A) \lor (D \land B \land C)  \lor (D \land C \land \sim A) \lor (D \land C) 
$$

We now erase the disjuncts that are smaller than another disjunct.

$$
 (A \land C) \lor (A \land \sim D)    \lor (D \land B \land \sim A)  \lor (D \land C) 
$$

Which, by commutativity of $\land$, is equivalent to the expression you got. Therefore your solution was right.

Note that your solution is equivalent to $  (\sim A \land B \land D) \lor (A \land \sim D)   \lor (C \land D)$. Indeed, by the distributive law and the fact that $D \, \lor \sim D$ is equivalent to $1$, your solution is equivalent to
$$
 (\sim A \land B \land D) \lor (A \land \sim D)   \lor (C \land D) \lor (A \land C \land D) \lor (A \land C \land \sim D).
$$

Since the two last disjuncts are smaller than the third and second ones, it is equivalent to

$$
 (\sim A \land B \land D) \lor (A \land \sim D)   \lor (C \land D) .
$$